# Where does Sequel Pro / MAMP store local databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, macos, mamp

I had a few databases created on my computer via Sequel Pro & MAMP, and was running localhost to view them. However, I did a fresh install of Mac OS Lion, and I forgot to backup the databases to .sql files.

I do backup my files regularly, and have a copy of the computer pre-install. Does anyone know the path to the db files? Are they stored in a format that I could rebuild, so I could import into Sequel Pro?

Comment: Even if you have the slightest idea as to where SQL databases are stored locally...

Comment: Sequal Pro is a database client, it doesn't store data anywhere.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Brian W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788338/brian-w) didn't really help with me using MAMP Pro (v2.1.4), but luckily someone else did. Location for mine were:

/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql

They also said that they've moved it to Dropbox and then used a unix symlink for the original location (not a Mac OS X alias as they don't work), that way it does get backed up as well.

Comment: This was the version that helped me as well. I think this is the correct answer for the newest version of MAMP Pro as of this writing.

Answer (score 20):

Okay, I figured it out. If you are using MAMP and localhost to create databases, you just need to go to MAMP > db > mysql folder and in there will be all your databases.

Hope that helps anyone who uses Sequel Pro / MAMP / Localhost!

Comment: That's not guaranteed to be where there are.  InnoDB is now the default storage engine for MAMP.  These links may help those who are looking: http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/how-tos/check-the-default-storage-engine-of-mysql  http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/how-tos/set-the-mysql-default-storage-engine    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

Comment: If you are on good old MAMP, they will be located at /Applications/MAMP/db/ and if you are on MAMP Pro, they are located at /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/

Answer (score 3):

**To carry over previous databases** from Standard MAMP to MAMP PRO:

copy over 
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ 
into 
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/

**To carry over previous database users** you need to copy over: 
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/mysql/ 
into
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can also find more informations about the MAMP Directories (including the db files, error logs, etc.) in the Sequel Pro Docs (MAMP, MAMP PRO, XAMPP, Zend, etc.):
https://sequelpro.com/docs/ref/mysql/mysql-files

That helped me quiet a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For MAMP PRO 4.2.0 on a Windows 10 machine this info can be found as follows:

1. open in a text editor the mysql ini file

   ```
   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\conf\my.ini
   ```
2. look for the 'datadir' entry

In my case it is:

```
datadir = C:/Users/Public/Documents/Appsolute/MAMPPRO/db/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the path to your data dynamically by running this command

`mysqladmin -h host -u root -p variables`

of course you have to change host to your host (most likely to be) `localhost` 
and root to your username or `root` in case your using it as the default user
after entering your pass in the prompt you will get a long list of variables 
search for `datadir` that's where your databases are stored

Answer (score 0):

MAMP store its databases into this folder:

```
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
```