# Recovering local wordpress sites after reinstalling mamp?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp, local

So after doing some reading it looks like I've made a rookie mistake. My mamp servers weren't starting and I couldn't figure out what the problem was so I deleted and reinstalled mamp. After doing this I realized my sites were gone. I naively thought that 'local development' meant that the sites we're stored on my computer, and deleting mamp wouldn't do anything. Can someone confirm this? Are my sites gone for good? I still have the folders on my computer with all the files where I thought the sites were stored, can I do anything with those folders?

Comment: Wordress, to work, use the files in those folders that you still have, and a database (Phpmyadmin) that you have uninstalled, so I'm sorry but your databases are gone...

Comment: That's what I thought. What should I have done in my case? Since my servers weren't starting

Comment: So I would have tried to look up what was happening there with the servers, and try to make a backup to the database before uninstalling... 
When your web be in a hosting, usually they make a diary backup so you don't have to worry!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341897/where-does-sequel-pro-mamp-store-local-databases I'm not sure if this helpful, but maybe knowing this could have worked too...

Comment: Exactly which folders do you still have? Re: "I still have the folders on my computer with all the files where I thought the sites were stored, can I do anything with those folders?"

Answer (score 0):

MAMP is local development, but MAMP is a self-contained localhost system and doesn't interact with the localhost server on your Mac/PC, which has its own web directory, server (Apache), and PHP. (MySQL isn't always shipped/installed).

If you deleted the MAMP folder, yes, you deleted your databases, too.

If you have issue with MAMP running, you need to try restarting MAMP first, and then check within MAMP to be sure Apache and the database server are running.

If you wanted to delete MAMP and start over and then start a new WordPress instance, you needed to export your database using PHPMyAdmin and save the wp-content directory.